# will the induced width of a graph reduced being removed an edge

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I would like to know if I remove an edge from an undirected graph, will the induced width of it be reduced? How to prove it or where can I find a prove of it? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing an edge from a graph will not increase its induced width.

Given a vertex ordering `<`, the set of edges that we union in to determine its induced width is

```
{uv | exist vertices u, v, w such that u, v adjacent to w and u, v < w}.
```

This is a subset for the graph minus an edge, since every `u, v, w` tuple that witnesses the inclusion of `uv` works in the original graph too.

Comment: is there any possibility to prove that the induced width will not always remain the same if I remove an edge from the graph?

Comment: @breadbread1984 If you remove all of the edges, the width goes from positive to zero, so by the discrete intermediate value theorem...